# How to purge a queue in ActiveMQ Artemis programmatically using Java?

Tags: java, queue, activemq-artemis, purge

I am new to using ActiveMQ Artemis, and I am trying to purge one queue programmatically. I have searched through the documentation, and online but have not been able to find anything to help with this.

I would like an example of how to do this given a name if a queue using Java.

```java
ClientSessionFactory sessionFactory;
ClientSession session
ClientProducer producer

//Creating the queue as follows:
session = sessionFactory.createSession();
producer = session.createProducer(queueName);
session.start();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using the core API?

Comment: For performance and efficiency and compatibility with older versions

Comment: FWIW, the broker maintains backwards compatibility with all the protocols it supports so that older clients should always work with newer brokers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most messaging APIs and protocols do not provide a way to purge (i.e. clear *all* messages from) a queue. The two basic operations you normally get are producing and consuming. Such is the case with the "core" API provided by ActiveMQ Artemis.

That said, there is a **management** API which provides a way to purge a queue because this is something typically reserved for administrators who may be managing the broker. The management API is based on JMX MBeans so it can be accessed via JMX and a handful of other methods (e.g. web console, HTTP via Jolokia, management "messages").

For Java applications the `jmx` example which ships with ActiveMQ Artemis in the `examples/features/standard/jmx` directory demonstrates exactly what you want to do. It uses the [`removeMessages` method of the `QueueControl`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/QueueControl.html#removeMessages(java.lang.String)) with a `null` filter value to remove all the messages from the queue. Here's a quick summary:

```java
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.RoutingType;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.SimpleString;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.ObjectNameBuilder;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.QueueControl;

...

ObjectName on = ObjectNameBuilder.DEFAULT.getQueueObjectName(SimpleString.toSimpleString(queueName), SimpleString.toSimpleString(queueName), RoutingType.ANYCAST);
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi"));
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
QueueControl queueControl = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(mbsc, on, QueueControl.class, false);
queueControl.removeMessages(null);
```

For more details on running the examples see the ["Examples" chapter in the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/examples.html).

For more details on the management API and broker management in general (including configuration changes necessary to enable [remote JMX access](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#remote-jmx-access)) see the ["Management" chapter in the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html).